# Ruby on Rails Application Page Does Not Exist in Heroku Production Environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

In my app during testing on `localhost` I am able to click on a link that brings me to the `edit_event_path(event)` page and it works perfectly.

When I pushed it to Heroku I keep getting the error "This page does not exist" however I am still able to access the `/event` index page.

It only appears to be for the edit page.

My routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :approvals
  devise_for :users
  resources :events

  resources :roles
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  scope "/admin" do
    resources :users do
      collection do
        match 'update_collection', via: [:put, :patch]
      end
    end
  end
  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root 'events#index'

  # Example of regular route:
  #   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'

  # Example of named route that can be invoked with purchase_url(id: product.id)
  #   get 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', as: :purchase

  # Example resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Example resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Example resource route with more complex sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', on: :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with concerns:
  #   concern :toggleable do
  #     post 'toggle'
  #   end
  #   resources :posts, concerns: :toggleable
  #   resources :photos, concerns: :toggleable

  # Example resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end
end
```

Heroku Logs

```
 2016-02-07T18:10:42.416537+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-02-07 18:10:42] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
    2016-02-07T18:10:42.417158+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-02-07 18:10:42] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3 port=33086
    2016-02-07T18:10:42.416617+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-02-07 18:10:42] INFO  ruby 2.2.4 (2015-12-16) [x86_64-linux]
    2016-02-07T18:10:42.689042+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
    2016-02-07T18:10:44.112872+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=rocky-garden-45285.herokuapp.com request_id=68c4f973-c80d-4c5a-8fcb-b0278f2cbf91 fwd="31.54.189.126" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=270ms status=200 bytes=3966
    2016-02-07T18:10:44.310780+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-f963057a4622f6dd81c09aa4b5984113c498b7784f67dfc6ef8bff81e17352df.css" host=rocky-garden-45285.herokuapp.com request_id=9fae1fe7-dceb-451a-836f-e52cda494151 fwd="31.54.189.126" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=23ms status=304 bytes=133
    2016-02-07T18:10:44.535082+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-6abdf7298b102105c44b987e39846d7496e6a9c5e36a3eac9c8e68189eaa9865.js" host=rocky-garden-45285.herokuapp.com request_id=759a6a46-fe88-4db6-8c09-d79a1a9d005d fwd="31.54.189.126" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=22ms status=304 bytes=133
    2016-02-07T18:10:45.045464+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/submit.png" host=rocky-garden-45285.herokuapp.com request_id=32c0080b-4eea-493a-a49a-73a517d5339d fwd="31.54.189.126" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=90ms status=304 bytes=343
    2016-02-07T18:10:45.061932+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/pencil.png" host=rocky-garden-45285.herokuapp.com request_id=b05f2f39-6f94-44a7-89e7-1a4cd20d2afb fwd="31.54.189.126" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=302ms status=304 bytes=343
    2016-02-07T18:10:45.042709+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/doc.png" host=rocky-garden-45285.herokuapp.com request_id=efaa4827-c548-485f-8d82-e98313823573 fwd="31.54.189.126" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=303ms status=304 bytes=343
    2016-02-07T18:10:48.512052+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/events/1/edit" host=rocky-garden-45285.herokuapp.com request_id=72bfc70a-ef5b-401b-9b62-cf7f1f2f14c1 fwd="31.54.189.126" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=22ms status=404 bytes=1829
    2016-02-07T18:10:48.644811+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/events/1/edit" host=rocky-garden-45285.herokuapp.com request_id=64f69780-d399-4f81-9354-b7998b98afb2 fwd="31.54.189.126" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=12ms status=404 bytes=1829
    2016-02-07T18:10:52.675030+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/events/1/edit" host=rocky-garden-45285.herokuapp.com request_id=50101311-033a-4dda-a4fb-c750144f8685 fwd="31.54.189.126" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=13ms status=404 bytes=1829
    2016-02-07T18:10:52.805759+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/events/1/edit" host=rocky-garden-45285.herokuapp.com request_id=0b665b71-6949-47da-9061-78d7a9014b3a fwd="31.54.189.126" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=11ms status=404 bytes=1829
```

EventsController

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_event, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_users
  before_action :set_user, except: [:index]

  # GET /events
  # GET /events.json
  def index
    @events = Event.where(:approved => true)
    @users = User.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end

  # GET /events/1
  # GET /events/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /events/new
  def new
    @event = Event.new
  end

  # GET /events/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /events
  # POST /events.json
  def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.save
        format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @event }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /events/1
  # PATCH/PUT /events/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.update(event_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @event }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /events/1
  # DELETE /events/1.json
  def destroy
    @event.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to events_url, notice: 'Event was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_event
      @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_users
      @users = User.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.

    def event_params
      params.require(:event).permit(:name, :user_id)
    end
end
```

I am not sure if any other logs or such are required to answer my question but if you comment I will provide them! Thank you!

Comment: Logs from Heroku, `EventsController` code would help

Comment: Maybe the event doesn't exist in the database?

Comment: I've updated the post with both the logs and events controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine - it's likely there's no `Event` with ID 1. Either you haven't created any in production yet, or you already deleted it. `/events/1` will probably 404 as well.

Go to `/events/new` to create an `Event`. You can also log into your Heroku database with `heroku pg:psql` (assuming you have the [toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/) installed) and `SELECT id FROM events` to verify which IDs are present.

You're also loading `@user` using `params[:id]`, which is the `Event`'s ID. If a `User` doesn't exist with the same ID as the `Event`, Rails raises the same `RecordNotFound` exception, which is what comes back to you as a 404. It looks like you've got login on this application, so you probably want to be loading that from `session[:user_id]`, via Devise, or however else you built authentication.

Comment: It appears that whenever I try to access the `/events/new` page it also says `The page you were looking for does not exist`. Whenever I run `heroku run rails console` and search for the events, there is definitely an event with ID 1.

Comment: Marked your answer as correct as the issue was the `params[:id]`, however I had to use `current_user.id` as opposed to `session[:user_id]` just in case you want to update your answer. Thanks for the help!